# Async Function Causes Jasmine to Hang

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am writing some unit tests for a JavaScript module I've written. A part of the module connects to a REDIS database. I am connecting to that database using [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). My test, written in Jasmine 2.1, looks like this:

```
var ModuleService = require('./module-service');
describe("TEST", function() {
  var service = new ModuleService();

  var options = null;
  beforeEach(function() {
    options = {
      server: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 6379
    };
  });

  it('Connect to REDIS', function(done) {
    service.connectToRedis(options, function() {
      console.log('call back received.');
      expect(service.state).toBe('Open');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

My test executes. The state variable of the service is set to 'Open'. However, in the command-line, it just sits there. I have to do a Ctrl+C to get my command prompt back. If I remove the test, control is given to the command prompt immediately. This makes me believe that I am setting up my async stuff incorrectly. For the sake of completeness, my `connectToRedis` function looks like this:

```
var redis = require('redis');
function ModuleService() {
}
ModuleService.prototype.state = 'Not Ready';

ModuleService.prototype.connectToRedis = function(options, callback) {
  // Ensure that the options are being passed
  if (!options) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(-1);
    }
    return;
  }

  try {
    // Attempt to connect to the REDIS server
    this.state = 'Connecting to REDIS';
    client = redis.createClient(options.port, options.host, null);
    this.state = 'Open';

    if (callback) {
      callback(1);
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(-1);
    }
  }
};
module.exports = ModuleService;
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why doesn't control get returned to the command-line?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you disconnecting the client anywhere?

Comment: no. I just wanted to test that I could connect. Is a disconnect required?

Comment: You should have an afterEach that disconnects, otherwise even though the tests have finished, node will have no way of knowing that it can disconnect the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An open socket is one thing that will keep a node process open. You need to disconnect the client after the test completes to allow the process to exit naturally.